# Azure app services - Docker compose multi container app - no Docker logs

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I am trying to deploy a multi-container web application to Azure App Services.  The application runs fine from the images on my local machine however when I try to run it on app services it does not work and there are no error messages.  In the logs section it says, "error retrieving logs."

[image: Image of error]

Bellow is the YAML for my docker compose file, I have tried various different version of this, but I am never able to get any error messages from Azure.

**What am I doing wrong? How do I get Docker logs from Azure app services?**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: ptd_reports_app
    command: gunicorn TransitData.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/PublicTransitDataReportingPortal/web/staticfiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    restart: always
    environment:
       DEBUG=1
       SECRET_KEY=<secret key>
       DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
       EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=<email password>
  nginx:
    image: ptd_reports_nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/PublicTransitDataReportingPortal/web/staticfiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  static_volume:
```

Answer (score 5):

I found [this entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/186815/deploying-via-docker-compose-to-app-center-with-mu.html) when dealing with the same issue. Basically you need to have port 80 or 8080 exposed (other ports are ignored), and use the correct syntax:

```
ports:
- "80:80"
```

And there is only a tiny subset of all docker-compose options actually working according to the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options).