# Blank logs for Azure App service in multi-container configuration

Tags: azure, docker, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have been running an App Service with a multi-container configuration for years, but recently the container logs are completely blank.

They used to be accessible from the SCM site via this URL:

```
https://<app-service>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker
```

Application logging is enabled, and as far as I haven't made any changes except to the deployed application code.

I have gone digging through a other StackOverflow/Microsoft support forum posts, but haven't found a solution yet. The issue is also very similar to this unresolved  StackOverflow post: [Azure app services - Docker compose multi container app - no Docker logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615516/azure-app-services-docker-compose-multi-container-app-no-docker-logs)

---

**Settings:**

`WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` is set to `true`

[image]

Docker-compose file:

```yaml
services:
  website:
    image: ghcr.io/company/website:latest
    environment:
      - "ENVIRONMENT=dev"
      - "PORT=8000"
    ports:
      - 0:8000

  api:
    image: ghcr.io/company/api:latest
    ports:
      - 0:8000
    restart: always

  websocket:
    image: ghcr.io/company/websocket:latest
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - 0:8000
    restart: always

  nginx:
    image: ghcr.io/company/nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - website
      - api
      - websocket
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
```

Comment: I noticed that too when demoing Web App for Containers over the years. Stopping and restarting the Web App solved the issue if I remember correctly.

Comment: @CSharpRocks Unfortunately still blank after restarting

Comment: You can check the Container logs at [Log Stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Zem.png).For Multiple containers you can select from the menu to choose container.

Comment: Please refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/log-streaming?tabs=bash)

Comment: @harshita Log stream is showing deployment logs, but no application logs. In your screenshot, it shows "listening on port 80", but that is missing for me.

Comment: @OscarHermoso Could you please share the Log stream Image.

Comment: @OscarHermoso Can you try finding the logs in Kudu in the advanced tools option?